# How do I dinamically create and add view of MvxFrameControl in another layout

Tags: mvvmcross

How can I dynamically create and add view to specific region of current view, for example create and add androids MvxFrameControl ?

I need some like on Android

```
 var frameHelpControl = (MvxFrameControl)ViewFactory.CreateByModel(frameHelpControlModel);
 regionForHelpFrame.AddView(frameHelpControl, new ViewGroupParameters(.....));
```

I need ability to create View by model via DI Factory and adding it to any region. I know that there exist such factory inside standart presenter but what if i need create controller for me without presenter?

For example, I have code in old iOS project

```
 private void AddBubble(BubbleMC newBubbleModel)
 {
       var bubble = (BubbleVC)ViewContollerFactory.ViewControllerByModel(newBubbleModel, true);            
       bubble.View.Frame = View.Bounds;            
       AddChildViewController(bubble);
       Add(bubble.View);
       bubble.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
 }
```

How can I rewrite it on mvvmCross Android / iOS (i think it will the same) for BubbleVC that will inherits MvxFrameControl and will needed to be added in View.

Answer (score 2):

You can load a ViewModel like this:

```
var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
var viewModelRequest = MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
var viewModel = loaderService.LoadViewModel(viewModelRequest, null);
```

Then you can just create a `MvxFrameControl` and assign the `BindingContext` the the newly created ViewModel.

However, instead of creating views and adding to a parent view, you should rely on the mechanic of something like RecyclerView on Android and TableView/CollectionView on iOS.